# If <div id='credits'> Removed From HTML Document Then Redirect to a New Web Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If a specific `<div id='credits'>` is removed from the HTML document, I want it the user to be redirected to a new web page using JavaScript.

For example:

```
<div id="credits"></div>
```

If someone removes it then users will be automatically redirected to my website.

This is to protect copyrights.

Comment: Just a note, but if someone removes the credit, they can easily just remove the JS that looks for the credit as well.

Comment: @IMSoP But what if you'd check if someone removed that JS? They'll never be able to get around that!

Comment: @Stijn http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radar_detector_detector ;)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you are worried about someone copying your page to their website, you can try this, though it is indeed absurdly easy to get around:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if($('#credits').length == 0)
     window.location = 'http://www.url.com'
</script>
```

Comment: Should be noted that this relies on jQuery or a similar `$`-defining library. `document.getElementById('credits') == null` would be a more portable version of the same thing.

Comment: True enough, but OP had included jQuery in the question tag list.

Comment: Ah, yes, so they had :)

Comment: i have this code but i don't know how to use it 
'code' "<a href="http://www.google.com/">Google</a>","html","#cradit","#cradit:visible","href","location","http://www.google.com/" 'code

Answer (score 0):

in your page load event you may check like following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var yourDiv=document.getElementById("credits");
  if(yourDiv===null || yourDiv===undefined)
     window.location="http://www.google.com";
});
```

or

```
window.onload=function(){
  var yourDiv=document.getElementById("credits");
      if(yourDiv===null || yourDiv===undefined)
         window.location="http://www.google.com";
}
```

Comment: Are we really having any tag as credits? You seem have just discovered that :-p

Comment: I was going to say plus one for a non-jQuery solution, but then noticed you've put it in a jQuery event anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
       if($("#your-div-id").length == 0) {
           window.location.href = "your-url";
       }
   });
</script>
```

Comment: `!$("#your-div-id")` will always be false, regardless of whether `#your-div-id` exists or not. You need to use `.length` like in the other answers.